# Mirroring Cloud Source Repositories to GitLab repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, dialogflow-es, mirroring

Is it possible to mirror from Cloud Source Repositories to GitLab repositories. Like I want to host the code in index.js in google dialogflow in our enterprise gitlab repository.